# Jenkins Kubernetes Serviceaccount Cannot list Pods

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

After creating a Service Account for Jenkins with the commands:

```
kubectl -n jenkins create sa jenkins

kubectl create clusterrolebinding jenkins --clusterrole cluster-admin --serviceaccount=jenkins:jenkins
```

and adding the certificate in Jenkins (Manage Jenkins --> Configure System --> Add Cloud) I get the error message

```
Error connecting to https://169.46.7.238:21769: 
Failure executing: GET at: 
https://169.46.7.238:21769/api/v1/namespaces/jenkins/pods. 
Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. 
Service account may have been revoked. 
User "system:serviceaccount:jenkins:default" cannot list pods in the namespace "jenkins"..
```

It seems like Jenkins tries to use the `default`Serviceaccount.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

This one is work for me
`kubectl create clusterrolebinding jenkins --clusterrole cluster-admin --serviceaccount=jenkins:default`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, could you try creating the service account `system:serviceaccount:jenkins:default` instead of `jenkins`?

Comment: @trahloff Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: sadly not. I don't know why

Comment: Is Jenkins running inside kubernetes? Which documentation are you following?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding jenkins --clusterrole admin -- 
serviceaccount=jenkins:default -n jenkins
```

Remember to replace the parameters.